# How can i justify text in crystal reports

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, and while building a report that contains a large amount of text, I cannot justify it, there are left, center, and right alignments in the toolbar but not justify, I remember it was there in previous versions.

How can I achieve justification?

there is a similar question here but it does not answer my question

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thankfully I've not used CR for some time (since VS2003) so cannot answer directly, but it used to be via a right-click on the object, and then select "Format Text"

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such option in the context menu anymore

Comment: Yeah, I assumed as much, just put the comment (rather than an Answer) in the highly unlikely hope that you hadn't tried right-clicking

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your column

Select Format object -> Common -> Horizontal Alignment -> Justified

Answer (score 0):

**solution for Justify in crystal report with visual studio 2010** 
**Right click on your Text Object
In format Editer

Paragraph -> Horizontal Alignment -> Alignment -> Justified**